# Como importo os dados de uma planilha no excel (csv) para uma tabela HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-excel

Olá, eu estou fazendo um site, que contém uma tabela, porém os dados dessa tabela precisam ser importados de uma planilha excel que tenho salvo aqui na minha máquina.. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Se possível, gostaria de utilizar javascript puro

Comment: No link tem um tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/parsing-a-csv-file-with-javascript--cms-25626 caso tenha dificuldade poste o código.

Comment: Cara, não sei se pensou nisso, ou até, se é esse seu problema mas, o cvs será importado para o server. Não faz muito sentido você trazer para o js fazer a conversão e aí jogar os dados na tela. Se eu fosse você, enviaria do server para o client, um JSON formatado, que o js entende muito bem, e aí sim iria popular a tela. Isso em meu pensamento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Envie um ajax para o seu arquivo `.csv` e coloque dentro da variável `resp` que no meu caso está dentro da função `popular()`

```js
function popular(){
 var resp = 'nome,sexo,peso\nmarcelo,M,70'; //"deveria" vir do ajax esses dados
 
 var th1  = document.querySelector(".th1"),
 th2      = document.querySelector(".th2"),
 th3      = document.querySelector(".th3"),
 td1      = document.querySelector(".td1"),
 td2      = document.querySelector(".td2"),
 td3      = document.querySelector(".td3");

 var rows = resp.split('\n');
 var cols  = [];
 rows.map(function(row){
  cols.push(row.split(/\, ?/));
 });

 th1.textContent = cols[0][0];
 th2.textContent = cols[0][1];
 th3.textContent = cols[0][2];

 td1.textContent = cols[1][0];
 td2.textContent = cols[1][1];
 td3.textContent = cols[1][2]; 

 console.log(cols);
}
popular();
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th1"></th>
      <th class="th2"></th>
      <th class="th3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td1"></td>
      <td class="td2"></td>
      <td class="td3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

É claro que você terá de implementar conforme suas necessidades, isso foi apenas um noção de como você poderia fazer;

Comment: Ok, vou tentar aqui e já respondo

Comment: Nao entendi o motivo de ser negativado